# How to read the first byte of a subprocess's stdout and then discard the rest in Python?

Tags: python, stream, subprocess

I'd like to read the first byte of a subprocess' stdout to know that it has started running. After that I'd like to discard all further output, so that I don't have to worry about the buffer.

What is the best way to do this?

**Clarification:** I'd like the subprocess to continue running alongside my program, I don't want to wait for it to terminate or anything like that. Ideally there would be some simple way to do this, without resorting to `threading`, `fork`ing or `multiprocessing`.

If I ignore the output stream, or `.close()` it, it causes errors if it is sent more data than it can fit in its buffer.

Comment: Does my answer not do exactly what you want?  Launches subprocess, reads the first byte, then continues running the process in parallel...

Comment: As far as I can tell, it would continue to read `stdout` and `stderr` into a buffer, wasting memory. I'm not sure, but this could also result in the subprocess blocking if the buffer fills up. I would like to avoid this.

Comment: his solution won't block, since it never reads anything past the 1st byte. but you can't tell when it's done. `wait` will not read anything, but might block (if the program writes too much and starts waiting for the OS to read the pipe). my `communicate` won't, and it will read the contents, taking up memory. but you cant know when the process ends without reading... let me offer another solution

Comment: @Jeremy I modified my example to prove that no memory is wasted.  Run and watch the memory usage of the process with your process monitor.  It never goes up.

Comment: I have tested it, and the second process blocks once `stdout` buffer in the first process is full.

Comment: Ah, so it does.  +1 for working code.  Btw, you've got an stdout where an stdin should be on line 11 :p

Comment: If you want to know that the subprocess has "started running", or if it is still running, you do not need to read a byte of output.  If you need some signal from the process that it has reached a certain state, modify that process to provide the indicator: have it create a file, or send a signal, or make a tcp connection, or send a message, or something reasonable.  If you really want to check output, probably the simplest thing would be to connect the subprocess' stdout to a file, wait until that file gets a character written to it, then unlink it.  This is not robust, but it's easy.

Answer (score 67):

If you're using Python 3.3+, you can use the `DEVNULL` special value for `stdout` and `stderr` to discard subprocess output.

```
from subprocess import Popen, DEVNULL

process = Popen(["mycmd", "myarg"], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
```

Or if you're using Python 2.4+, you can simulate this with:

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen

DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
process = Popen(["mycmd", "myarg"], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=DEVNULL)
```

However this doesn't give you the opportunity to read the first byte of stdout.

Comment: In other words...it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It answers the question in the title of the post. Therefore I think it would be useful to others who reach this page in an internet search.

Comment: Does this interfere with `subprocess.check_call`? I wouldn't think so, since exit status is given by `wait`, however, just to be sure.

Comment: This technique also works with check_call because it takes the same parameters as Popen.

Comment: `DEVNULL` did not work for me. I am using Python 3.2.3

Comment: @richard needs python 3.3+... doesn't work for me in 3.4 anyway :/

Comment: @Wilf Did you say it works for all > 3.3, and does not work for 3.4 ?

Comment: @richard its new in 3.3, so presumably it is should work in most builds of 3.3 and later (just not my build of python3 which may be missing bits, or I am doing something wrong :) . I used the `DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'wb')` as a workaround anyway.

Comment: Works for me in 3.4.1.

Comment: Now the title is edited, but this one is the answer for [python - How to hide output of subprocess - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269575/how-to-hide-output-of-subprocess) . (okay this one is posted very long ago)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work, but it doesn't feel idiomatic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.1
import threading
import subprocess

def discard_stream_while_running(stream, process):
    while process.poll() is None:
        stream.read(1024)

def discard_subprocess_pipes(process, out=True, err=True, in_=True):
    if out and process.stdout is not None and not process.stdout.closed:
        t = threading.Thread(target=discard_stream_while_running, args=(process.stdout, process))
        t.start()

    if err and process.stderr is not None and not process.stderr.closed:
        u = threading.Thread(target=discard_stream_while_running, args=(process.stderr, process))
        u.start()

    if in_ and process.stdin is not None and not process.stdin.closed:
        process.stdin.close()
```

#### Example/test usage

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import tempfile
    import textwrap
    import time

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w+t", prefix="example-", suffix=".py") as f:
        f.write(textwrap.dedent("""
            import sys
            import time

            sys.stderr.write("{} byte(s) read through stdin.\\n"
                             .format(len(sys.stdin.read())))

            # Push a couple of MB/s to stdout, messages to stderr.
            while True:
                sys.stdout.write("Hello Parent\\n" * 1000000)
                sys.stderr.write("Subprocess Writing Data\\n")
                time.sleep(0.5)
        """))
        f.flush()

        p = subprocess.Popen(["python3.1", f.name],
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

        p.stdin.write("Hello Child\n".encode())

        discard_subprocess_pipes(p) # <-- Here

        for s in range(16, 0, -1):
            print("Main Process Running For", s, "More Seconds")
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: you are not waiting for the first byte to be read. Though: `p.poll() is None` after `Popen()` means that the subprocess *is* running. If it is all you need then you should [use `DEVNULL`-based solution instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12926181/4279).