# Why doesn't pdflatex work when called as a Python subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess, pdflatex

I am trying to implement a function in my Python script to compile a TeX file automatically. I am trying with the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html); this is what I'm doing:

```
def createpdf(output):
    args = ['pdflatex', output, '-interaction=nonstopmode']

    process = subprocess.call(args,
                    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
                    stdin  = subprocess.PIPE)
```

When I run pdflatex with my TeX file in the terminal, it compiles fine. But when I run my Python script, it doesn't compile. It seems like the compile process begins but after a couple of minutes, it stops without any reason. I looked in the log file and it doesn't print any error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set an output pipe to `subprocess.PIPE`, subprocess creates a buffer to hold the subprocess' output until it's read by your process. If you never read from `process.stdout` and `process.stderr`, pdflatex can fill up the buffer and block.

You need to either [discard their output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5495078/1114) or just call `subprocess.call(args)` and let them flow through your program's output.

Comment: thanks Jeremy... I read in another page that I need those PIPEs but after I remove them everything works perfect.... thanks a lot!!! :)