# Is there a quiet version of subprocess.call?

Tags: python, subprocess, silent

Is there a variant of `subprocess.call` that can run the command without printing to standard out, or a way to block out it's standard out messages?

Comment: Closely related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495078/how-do-you-discard-subprocess-output-in-python , in particular because call uses Popen.

Comment: related: [How to hide output of subprocess in Python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes. Redirect its `stdout` to `/dev/null`.

```
process = subprocess.call(["my", "command"], stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb'))
```

Answer (score 54):

Often that kind of chatter is coming on stderr, so you may want to silence that too.  Since Python 3.3, [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) has this feature directly:

> To suppress stdout or stderr, supply a value of [DEVNULL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL).

Usage:

```
import subprocess
rc = subprocess.call(args, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

If you are still on Python 2:

```
import os, subprocess

with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as shutup:
    rc = subprocess.call(args, stdout=shutup, stderr=shutup)
```

Comment: noticing that no answer is taking about using `startupinfo` as shown here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/409002-launching-a-subprocess-without-a-console-window/ to avoid window flashing when running python out of a console

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'd never even heard of it. Might be something Windows specific?

Comment: probably, yes. If you want to fight epilepsy on windows, that's a must-have.

Answer (score -1):

This is a recipe I use a lot: call `subprocess` and collect the output, and when the command succeeds discard the output, but when it fails print the output.

```
import subprocess as sp
import sys

if "print" in __builtins__.__dict__:
    prn = __builtins__.__dict__["print"]
else:
    def prn(*args, **kwargs):
        """
        prn(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\\n', file=sys.stdout)
        Works just like the print function in Python 3.x but can be used in 2.x.

        Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
        Optional keyword arguments:
        file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
        sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
        end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.
        """
        sep = kwargs.get("sep", ' ')
        end = kwargs.get("end", '\n')
        file = kwargs.get("file", sys.stdout)

        s = sep.join(str(x) for x in args) + end
        file.write(s)


def rc_run_cmd_basic(lst_cmd, verbose=False, silent=False):
    if silent and verbose:
        raise ValueError("cannot specify both verbose and silent as true")

    p = sp.Popen(lst_cmd, stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
    tup_output = p.communicate()

    s_cmd = ' '.join(lst_cmd)
    if verbose:
        prn()
        prn("command: '%s'\n" % s_cmd)

        if 0 != p.returncode:
            prn()
            prn("Command failed with code %d:" % p.returncode)
        else:
            prn("Command succeeded!  code %d" % p.returncode)
    if verbose:
        prn("Output for: " + s_cmd)
        prn(tup_output[0])
        prn()
    if not silent and 0 != p.returncode:
        prn("Error output for: " + s_cmd)
        prn(tup_output[1])
        prn()

    return p.returncode
```

Comment: This is (poorly) reinventing functionality already in `subprocess`. It's easier to handle the [`CalledProcessError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError), which has attributes for the captured stdout and stderr on it already.

Answer (score -1):

I use subprocess.check_output in such cases and drop the return value. You might want to add a comment your code stating why you are using check_output in place of check_call. check_output is also nicer when a failure occurs and you are interested in the error output. Example code below. The output is seen only when you uncomment the print line. If the command fails, an exception is thrown.

```
import subprocess
ret = subprocess.check_output(["cat", "/tmp/1"])
#print ret
```

Comment: How does dropping the return value prevent the output to stdout?

Comment: subprocess.check_output is supposed to capture the output and return it. Are you seeing a different behavior?

Comment: Capturing and ignoring works, but wastes memory on the captured value which is then never used. Discarding the output properly is more robust.

Comment: I agree memory will be wasted. But for small commands which just outputs few bytes, it is OK. Depends on your use-case. Better solution is to redirect to /dev/null as suggested in the accepted solution.