# How to suppress or capture the output of subprocess.run()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

From the examples in docs on [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) it seems like there shouldn't be any output from

```py
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])  # doesn't capture output
```

However, when I try it in a python shell the listing gets printed. I wonder if this is the default behaviour and how to suppress the output of `run()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529390/is-there-a-quiet-version-of-subprocess-call

Comment: `subprocess.run()` doesn't capture stdout or stderr by default, to do so requires passing `PIPE`s for the `stdout` and/or `stderr` arguments (it's right in the linked documentation). So, unless you do, they will display as they normally would from the other process.

Comment: Do you want to suppress the output or capture it?

Comment: @SethMMorton: right now I just need to hide it.

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate, but I think this is a mistake, because the API changed significantly between Python 2.7 (`process.call`), and Python 3.5 (`process.run`).

I came here explicitly looking for the Python 3 answer to this question.

The accepted answer for this question, and the top comment on it, are both more useful in that context than the answers on the other question.

Comment: Since [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html) you can also just use the `capture_output=True` parameter.

Comment: Agree that this question shouldn't be marked as duplicated. `subprocess.run` is the only high-level API recommended in the subprocess module since Python 3.5.

Comment: What do y'all mean by capture? Where does the output go when I capture it?

Answer (score 373, accepted):

## Suppressing

Here is how to *suppress* output, in order of decreasing levels of cleanliness. They assume you are on Python 3.

1. You can redirect to the special `subprocess.DEVNULL` target.

```
import subprocess

# To redirect stdout (only):
subprocess.run(
    ['ls', '-l'],
    stdout = subprocess.DEVNULL
)

# to redirect stderr to /dev/null as well:
subprocess.run(
    ['ls', '-l'],
    stdout = subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stderr = subprocess.DEVNULL
)

# Alternatively, you can merge stderr and stdout streams and redirect
# the one stream to /dev/null
subprocess.run(
    ['ls', '-l'],
    stdout = subprocess.DEVNULL,
    stderr = subprocess.STDOUT
)
```

2. If you want a fully manual method, can redirect to `/dev/null` by opening the file handle yourself. Everything else would be identical to method #1.

```
import os
import subprocess

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
    subprocess.run(
        ['ls', '-l'],
        stdout = devnull
    )
```

---

## Capturing

Here is how to *capture* output (to use later or parse), in order of decreasing levels of cleanliness. They assume you are on Python 3.

> NOTE: The below examples use `universal_newlines=True` (Python <= 3.6).
>
> - This causes the STDOUT and STDERR to be captured as `str` instead of `bytes`.
>
>   - Omit `universal_newlines=True` to get `bytes` data
> - Python >= 3.7 accepts `text=True` as a short form for `universal_newlines=True`

1. If you simply want to capture both STDOUT and STDERR independently, AND you are on Python >= 3.7, use `capture_output=True`.

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(
    ['ls', '-l'],
    capture_output = True, # Python >= 3.7 only
    text = True # Python >= 3.7 only
)
print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)
```

2. You can use `subprocess.PIPE` to capture STDOUT and STDERR independently. This works on *any* version of Python that supports `subprocess.run`.

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(
    ['ls', '-l'],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines = True # Python >= 3.7 also accepts "text=True"
)
print(result.stdout)

# To also capture stderr...
result = subprocess.run(
    ['ls', '-l'],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines = True # Python >= 3.7 also accepts "text=True"
)
print(result.stdout)
print(result.stderr)

# To mix stdout and stderr into a single string
result = subprocess.run(
    ['ls', '-l'],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr = subprocess.STDOUT,
    universal_newlines = True # Python >= 3.7 also accepts "text=True"
)
print(result.stdout)
```

Comment: Note that from Python ver. 3.3 there is actually a `subprocess.DEVNULL`, so `stdout` argument can be assigned directly without the `open`, just using `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL`.

Comment: I'm getting `NameError: name 'devnull' is not defined` on Python 3.7

Comment: @Sabrina Have you defined `devnull`?

Comment: Is it possible to print the output while simultaneously capturing the data in a pipe (to use later or parse)?

Comment: @Christopher If you don't care about printing while the program is running, you can just print `result.stdout` after-the-fact. If you want to capture and print real-time, it's a bit more complicated because you cannot use `subprocess.run`, you need the lower-level `subprocess.Popen`. I have used something [like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6414278/1399279) when I need to do that (adjust syntax from answer for Python 3).

Comment: Note that despite your answer accidentally making it look like the opposite is true, your `subprocess.PIPE` examples above DO work with Python < 3.7, such as Python 3.6.

Comment: I've edited your answer and noted that in your answer.

Comment: Huh, I never would have read that as implying they did not work on < 3.7. But, I’m glad you made it that much clearer

Comment: i;m only getting <_io.BufferedReader name=3> as an output

Comment: i was runing my flask server in one subprocess in the bg and then starting tests in another subprocess but the outcome was a nightmare!  doing   subprocess.run(['my', 'process'], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)   did let my server process work on the background while the second subprocess test run at the same time with out clogging the outputs/prints,  and if something goes wrong with the first subprocess(the server) i will still get that print.    super thanks for the examples!

Comment: Note that while the PIPE works **in Python < 3.7, there is no keyword `text`**, so you can only get a bytestring by default and the code above will crash

Comment: @Epanemu That is why the answer has these statements: "`text=True` is Python >= 3.7 only, use `universal_newlines=True` on Python <= 3.6.
`universal_newlines=True` is identical to `text=True` but more verbose to type but should exist on all Python versions"

Answer (score 28):

ex: to capture the output of `ls -a`

```
import subprocess
ls = subprocess.run(['ls', '-a'], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout.strip("\n")
print(ls)
```

Comment: this works for python 3.7, though not for python 3.6 (I get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'`)

Comment: the last part helps get a clean output to a variable.

Comment: How does`t work in Flask?

Comment: @Алексей I'm not sure what you mean. This should work fine in Flask, which is still running in a plain Python script and has access to the filesystem, same as any other Python script without Flask.