# suppress shell output while using python subprocess

Tags: python, linux, shell, automation, subprocess

I am Running a python script to run download commands using shell script and subprocess

```
import subprocess

script = download.sh
log = open(logfile.txt,"a")
subprocess.run(script,shell=True,stdout=log)
log.close()
```

I want to supress the downloading indicatior part which is visible when you run when the download starts[image: Text_to_supress]

I want to supress that part.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress or capture the output of subprocess.run()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171791/how-to-suppress-or-capture-the-output-of-subprocess-run)

Answer (score 0):

you need to capture the stderr as well:

```
subprocess.run(script,shell=True,stdout=log,stderr=log)
```