# python - How to redirect the errors to /dev/null?

Tags: linux, python

I have this fun in my python script:

```
def start_pushdata_server(Logger):
    Logger.write_event("Starting pushdata Server..", "INFO")
    retcode, stdout, stderr = run_shell(create_shell_command("pushdata-server 
start"))
```

we want to redirect the standard error from pushdata-server binary to /dev/null.

so we edit it like this:

```
def start_pushdata_server(Logger):
    Logger.write_event("Starting pushdata Server..", "INFO")
    retcode, stdout, stderr = run_shell(create_shell_command("pushdata-server 
start 2>/dev/null"))
```

But adding the `2>/dev/null`  in the python code isn't valid.

So how we can in the python code to send all errors from "pushdata-server 
start" to null?

Comment: no need to add `2>/dev/null`. Python will capture `stderr` if you specified the respective option. Learn and use `subprocess` module

Comment: the problem is that output from command (errors) send to standard output "to the screen" so we want to avoid that

Comment: Where and how is `run_shell` defined? Why do you want to run the server inside a shell?

Answer (score 5):

This code added to a Python script running in Unix or Linux will redirect all stderr output to /dev/null

```
import os # if you have not already done this
fd = os.open('/dev/null',os.O_WRONLY)
os.dup2(fd,2)
```

If you want to do this for only part of your code:

```
import os # if you have not already done this
fd = os.open('/dev/null',os.O_WRONLY)
savefd = os.dup(2)
os.dup2(fd,2)
```

The part of your code to have stderr redirected goes here.  Then to restore stderr back to where it was:

```
os.dup2(savefd,2)
```

If you want to do this for stdout, use 1 instead of 2 in the `os.dup` and `os.dup2` calls (`dup2` stays as `dup2`) and flush stdout before doing any group of `os.` calls.  Use different names instead of `fd` and/or `savefd` if these are conflicts with your code.

Comment: can you advice me please based on my code how to re-edit it based on your solution ?

Comment: @yael i do not know about your `run_shell()` and `create_shell_command()` functions so i do not know if i can work correctly with your code.  did you write those functions?  there may also be alternate, and perhaps better, ways to do this in those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding the complexities of the `run_shell(create_shell_command(...))` part which isn't well-defined anyway, try

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['pushdata-server', 'start'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

This doesn't involve a shell at all; your command doesn't seem to require one.

Comment: Basically stolen (with updates for recent Python 3.x) from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529390/is-there-a-quiet-version-of-subprocess-call