# How to save results but don't show output in the terminal

Tags: python, bash, stdout, io-redirection, error-suppression

I am trying to write a script that extracts wifi passwords. The problem is, I don't want it to show output before it's fully done.

```
from subprocess import check_output
raw = check_output('security find-generic-password -ga test > /dev/null 2>&1',\
shell=True)
```

If I suppress output like this, then even variables won't get any output for further uses. So how to suppress output, but save it in a variable.

Comment: Don't redirect the output to `/dev/null`. The default for `check_output()` is to save the output.

Comment: Then it shows output in the terminal as well, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: No it won't. `check_output()` redirects stdout to a pipe and captures the pipe's contents.

Comment: If it's generating errors and you want to capture that, use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to merge them.

Comment: Use `raw = run('security ... -ga test', capture_output=True)` to automatically capture both standard output and standard error. The contents of each are then accessible from `raw.stdout` and `raw.stderr`, respectively.

Comment: what system do you use? unfortunately subprocess provide command execution and return result to output. `/dev/null` - not bad. I found similar topic with similar answers) [quiet version of subprocess.call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8529412/3764369) [discard subprocess output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12926181/3764369)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ping=$(ls >> output.txt)
rm -rf output.txt
```

Assume the above scenario. I am piping the sttdout to a file then removing the file. Result is the output is not seen.